# Create a component as a member in an object instance

Tags: qml, qt5, qtquick2

I have a QML component called MyComponent and I have an instance of it as follows:

```
MyComponent {
    id: rightComponent

    property Component settingsScreen: SettingsScreen {}

    StackView {
        id: settingsStack
        anchors.fill: parent
        initialItem: rightComponent.settingsScreen
    }
}
```

`SettingsScreen` is another component that I have. The problem is that it does not seem that `rightComponent` is the parent of `settingsScreen`. I get the correct result when I embed as:

```
MyComponent {
    id: rightComponent

    SettingsScreen {}
}
```

This is fine and everything is laid out correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve as it follows:

```
MyComponent {
    id: rightComponent

    SettingsScreen {
        id: settingsScreen
    }

    StackView {
        id: settingsStack
        anchors.fill: parent
        initialItem: settingsScreen
    }
}
```

There is no need to define a new property as you did.

Comment: This works but the layout is all different when compared with removing the StackView component for some reason....

Comment: Ok, ignore my last comment. That was something completely different and your answer solved my issues. So thanks :)